# Asymptotics for the number of primality radii modulo k

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a large enough positive integer and define the notion of primality radius of $n$ modulo $k$ as a positive integer $r$ such that  $(n-r\pmod k,n+r\pmod k)\in\mathbb{P}_{1}^{2}$ where $\mathbb{P}_{1}$ is the set of primes to which we add the singleton $\{1\}$.

For fixed $k$, can we get an asymptotics for the number of primality radii of $n$ modulo $k$?